Bass diffusion model in R, not working with annual data
I want to use a bass diffusion model in R.
I used the following code:
library(diffusion)

years <- c(2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023)
adopters <- c(1000, 2500, 6000, 13000, 28000, 45000, 72000, 110000)

bass_model <- diffusion(years, adopters, type = "bass")

I expected R to create a bass diffusion model. Instead I received the following error:
The following error is displayed:

Error in structure(list(type = type, call = sys.call(), w = w, y = y, : Object 'vOut' not found"

Did someone encounter a similar issue and can help me to fix this?

The diffusion(y,w,...) function expects y to be adoption per period and w to be curve parameters. When it is set to w = NULL, which is the default, all parameters are optimized. For more information on this function and its examples, run ?diffusion in the console.
So you just need adopters data for y.
diffusion(adopters, type = "bass")
# bass model

#Parameters:
#      Estimate p-value
#m 1326837.9106      NA
#p       0.0024      NA
#q       0.4935      NA

#sigma: 7660.9236

